# Install groovy o 12.04,Hash Sum mismatch?

Tags: ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow the instruction :
Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise)

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

Set up your keys

```
   wget http://packages.ros.org/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update
```

then ,that is this :

Hit http://packages.ros.org precise Release
Get:1 http://packages.ros.org precise/main i386 Packages [1,641 kB]
Ign http://packages.ros.org precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://packages.ros.org precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://packages.ros.org precise/main Translation-en_US
Fetched 1 B in 3s (0 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/packages.ros.org_ros_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

then ,I type:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop-fullat
that is this:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-groovy-desktop-full
```

I then check the directory:

`bob@bob-robot:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ ls ros-latest.list`

I have  search the similar answer,it may be the source problem ,
so how to solve it?
many thanks ,I am waiting the answer...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57846/install-groovy-o-12.04,hash-sum-mismatch?/) by [bobliao](https://answers.ros.org/users/2976/bobliao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2013-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try to remove the lists directory under /var/lib and then creat it again:

```
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo rm -fr lists
sudo mkdir lists
sudo mkdir lists/partial
```

And try updating again

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After that, follow the instructions under the installation guide again (Configuring repositories, set up the keys updating apt-get and installing)

---

Originally posted by [Gabrielcarioca](https://answers.ros.org/users/4321/gabrielcarioca/) with karma: 28 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bobliao](https://answers.ros.org/users/2976/bobliao/) on 2013-03-12**:
it doesn't work ,but still thanks .